# How to reference one model to another in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I know a bit that how to reference documents in Mongoose but certain things are not clear to me .

Basically what I know till now :

```
const Task = mongoose.model('task' , {

description : {
    type : String , 
    require : true , 
    trim : true 
} ,

completed : {
    type : Boolean ,
    default : false
} , 

owner : {
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ,
    required : true , 
    ref : 'User'
}
})
```

But what I don't understand is that how do mongoose relate to **_id** of the **Users** Model , why not some other field have the same type . Let me rephrase it with more complication , what if my **owner** type is set to **String** , there can be **multiple** fields of **String** type in **Users** model . How do we reference it then ?

Comment: Have a look at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals . I think you are looking for this.

Comment: @Hariwarshan , when we use ref as some object id of a certain Model , is it like it automatically knows where to which field to refer to ? And about virtuals my understanding is that , it is something which is acting as a field of an Model while populating and getting back the populated data but not making any changes to the actual data base , but what to do when we actually want to populate inside the database itself ?